# Apollo graphQL multiple mutations optimistic optimization

Tags: meteor, graphql, apollo

I'm working on the app with Meteor and Apollo v.2 client.

The app has a list of items. Each item can be ignored and moved to another list. The order containing items is received by ORDERS subscription.

I just added an optimistic UI for it and it works bad.

I expect it to work immediately moving all needed items to corresponding section. But when I click too fast on `-` button for example items start to jump (I suspect it is because all of my changes send as separate requests, and local optimistic changes become rewritten by server side version).

[image: Items list]

Here is a gif demo — http://www.giphy.com/gifs/w8f2lp51GuRFVRVnNM

```
toogleItemIgnore(item) {
const { toggleItemIgnore, resetShipmentAndWeight, order } = this.props;
toggleItemIgnore({ 
  variables: { itemId: item._id },
  optimisticResponse: {
    __typename: 'Mutation',
    toogleItemIgnore: {
      ...item,
      isIgnored: !item.isIgnored
    }
  },
  update: (proxy, { data: { toogleItemIgnore } }) => {
    const updatedItem = toogleItemIgnore;
    const orderQuery = { 
      query: ORDER_QUERY,
      variables: { 
        _id: order._id
      }
    };
    const query = proxy.readQuery(orderQuery);
    const resultItems = [...query.order.items.filter(item => item._id !== updatedItem._id), updatedItem];
    const result = {
      ...query,
      order: {
        ...query.order,
        items: resultItems
      }
    };
    proxy.writeQuery({...orderQuery, data: result});
  }

})
```

It seems like I need to optimize my queries and mutations somehow. So all mutations works locally (optimistic) and then I send a batch of them to the server and update all items at once.

What is a correct strategy to implement it with Apollo?

Comment: It would be helpful to update your answer to include 1) the expected behavior and 2) the behavior you're seeing instead, in detail. To provide guidance around how to arrive at the expected behavior, it would also be helpful to see your code, especially the functions called by `update` and `optimisticResponse`

Comment: @DanielRearden hey! Just updated the question ;-)